# Gitlab Runner autoscaling on AWS EC2 - failing to spawn instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to autoscale gitlab runners on AWS EC2.

Here is my **config.toml**:

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 2
log_level = "debug"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "t2.micro default VPC"
  limit = 20
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "xxxx"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      AccessKey = "xxxx"
      SecretKey = "xxxx"
      BucketName = "xxxx"
      BucketLocation = "us-west-2"
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 300
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-docker-machine-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-access-key=xxxx",
      "amazonec2-secret-key=xxxx",
      "amazonec2-ami=ami-090717c950a5c34d3",
      "amazonec2-region=us-west-2",
      "amazonec2-zone=c",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-xxxx",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-xxxx",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address=true",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.micro"
    ]
    OffPeakTimezone = ""
    OffPeakIdleCount = 0
    OffPeakIdleTime = 0
```

However, when the job is triggered , it is picked up by the runner and nothing happens. From the error it looks like the spawning of the instance is not successful.

Error:
[image: Runner Error]

What could be wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. The only thing that work for me was re-doing the whole process, but in the Configure Instance from the Launch Instance on AWS I specifically choose the subnet to be on zone a. I continued the process as described and got it to work first without the Spot Instances and after, with them.